# PoD page limits

Tags: pages, print-on-demand

LuLu has an 800 pp. limit on their PoD books. What are some other alternatives to LuLu that allow printing more pages per volume (e.g., 1200)?

Comment: Fiction, nonfiction, reference? Black and white interior, grayscale, color? Interior images requiring bleed? Hardcover or softcover? Trim size? Nation(s) where you expect it will be sold? Reason why it could not be 2 volumes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the alternative of Lulu for you is [Mybestseller](http://www.mybestseller.com). They can print 1200+ pages and have no limit as far as I know. But you should contact them for the specifications of your special order. Nothing is impossible!

Comment: I asked MyBestSeller and they said the upper limit was 900, but they didn't recommend more than 500.

Comment: That was probably back in the day (when I answered was back in 2017). Currently I wouldn't recommend it anymore for printing so many pages per volume. The Shopify Blog has more recently published a list of 10 printing on demand companies for bookprinting. (https://www.shopify.com/blog/print-on-demand-books)